# How to get how many days are in the current year?

Tags: sqlite

How do I get how many days are in the current year (365,366) using Sqlite?

`select contact_id as _id,data1,display_name, (strftime('%j',data1)-strftime('%j','now')+365) % 365 as indays from contact_birthday where indays >-200 order by indays asc, display_name asc LIMIT 25`

I would like to replace 365 with the valid days for a leap year.

Comment: I'm wondering.. in order to use Sqllite you must already use another, real programming language - why not get the amount of days with that? Should be easier to find help with

Comment: I am using this in a birthday calculation, see my edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could compute the difference in days between the start of this year and the start of next year, like so (a bit dirty, though):

```
sqlite> SELECT julianday('now', 'start of year', '+1 year') - julianday('now', 'start of year');
365
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query for how many days in a year:-
  `select add_months(trunc(sysdate,'year'), 12) - trunc(sysdate,'year') from dual`